# How to calculate strike price for an American put given its value at time 0 and the binomial tree of stock prices?

Tags: option-pricing, american-options

Given the interest rate, prices of the stock at time 0,1,2 where T=2 is the expiry date, and the value of the American put at time 0, how do I calculate its strike price? The question gives it the same value as the European put. Does this mean that it must have the same strike price as the European put?